# What would be a good community promotion ad?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As suggested in [an answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/167) to the earlier meta question about site promotion, one method is to craft a site promotion ad for use on already graduated SE sites. So the purpose of this question, which I based directly on the [analogous one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-would-be-a-good-community-promotion-ad) at mathematica.SE, is to solicit potential ads which are designed to promote chess.SE on more established SE sites.

Each graduated SE site has a meta question where people can submit these ads ([here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/community-promotion-ads-2012) is the one at physics.SE, for instance), and if they receive enough upvotes they will be automatically shown by the system on that site.
If we get consensus on something good here, then we can submit it to the community promotion ad questions on other sites for potential use.

When an actual community ad is submitted, it is required to be in a particular form (detailed in the mathematica.SE question linked to above). In particular, the image must be exactly 220x250 pixels, in GIF or PNG format (not animated), and hosted on SE's Imgur account. It's not strictly necessary for answers to this question to follow that format, but it would be convenient. Answers posted here should definitely include the three required elements: image, tagline, and URL.

Answer (score 8):

**@iglvzx** here! What do you guys think of this as a community ad?

> [image: iglvzx]

What should the `title` attribute (hover text) be?

Comment: @iglvzx, let me know if I've overstepped by posting this here. I'm just a fan of it.

Comment: No problem! I made an ad with the proper dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

Ed, I think you were thinking of something like this? 220x250 png using the "Got Milk" font.

[image: Got Game? - chess.stackexchange.com]

---

Currently posted on:

- [Gaming (Arqade)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5001/28423)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/854/17557)
- [SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5098/143213)
- [SciFi & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1995/7480)

When it gets to 6 upvotes, it will be displayed on those sites on the right sidebar.

Comment: Nice! .........

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: So how do we get it posted around?

Comment: @Danielδ. Well, we can submit this image (along with the appropriate links) as an answer in the "Community Promotion Ads - 2012" meta questions at SE sites that might be appropriate (e.g. Arqade and GameDev spring to mind). Once we post it as an answer at such places, it is up to those communities to decide, by voting it up/down, if it should get any "airtime." If it gets to +6 at a given site, it will show in that site's ads.

Comment: I say go for it!

Comment: I just noticed that your image has a transparent background rather than solid white. Some sites that might be good tries for the ad (e.g. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/) have dark backgrounds against which the current version looks poor. So I'm switching the pointer here to a white-background version. I'm also going to switch the image links at the sites where we already posted. (If this is a bad idea for some reason I'm not thinking of, we can always rollback.)

Comment: I don't see this on SuperUser SE.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Got game? Want more?]

---

I have no marketing or graphic design sense. I just made this one to break the ice, using James Tomasino's [very nice logo](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/99/167).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to create a logo so just sharing my view here. If it is accepted by users and mods then we can implement this.

I would like to suggest to promote our Chess.SE in Programming SEs like Linux/Unix, Database, Stack overflow etc. As we have the following posts:

> [Chess program for Linux/Unix console](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/chess-program-for-linux-unix-console).
>   
> [Alternative approaches to chess engine programming](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16292/alternative-approaches-to-chess-engine-programming).
>   
> [What are the common mistakes make by chess engines at ELO range 1500 - 1800?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/what-are-the-common-mistakes-make-by-chess-engines-at-elo-range-1500-1800)

And many such on [programming](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) [software](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) [engines](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) [database](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database)

In addition to these SEs, I think Puzzle.SE could also work. By stating like:

> Puzzled by playing chess? Ask your doubts in Chess.SE.