# Any possibility for Chess to graduate?

Tags: discussion, graduation

This site has been active for years, but it's never popular. Most of us (including myself) are programmers on Stack Overflow migrating to here. This site is still a beta. Look at the number of questions generated by chess.com and us! Their message board is flooded with questions. The moderators on this site rarely have anything to do.

Any possibility for us to graduate out from beta? We have very high answer rate, but we don't have enough questions!

**EDIT:**

My favourite site (https://quant.stackexchange.com) is a site for professional in financial mathematics. There are actually not many people who know how to ask/answer there, nowhere near the number of chess players. But they managed to graduate! They beat us in everything!! Traffic, number of questions, Google search, reputation... Somehow the site was able to attract some of the best financial mathematicians. But ... do we even have a grandmaster? I'm tempted to say the site is a failure (relative to other sites in the network).

Comment: How many forums on financial mathematics existed before Quant SE? There are tons of other sites where people can discuss and even play chess. Why would they come here instead of stay where they are? What makes Chess SE more attractive?

Comment: Someone made the following point before: Grandmasters get part of their income from advising amateurs online, so they have a direct incentive against giving away free advice. This is not true to the same degree for researchers in other fields..

Comment: Does it matter if we don't graduate? I reckon chess.se could get rolled back in with board games.

Comment: I agree the site is not very competitive with other sites on this topic. There are various other chess forums on the web which are more serious about chess, and have a higher level of content provided by better chess players. For instance if I would like to get serious advice about openings, I'd head to the chesspub.com forum - getting advice from amateurs here (no offence) would just not be very useful for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is useful to post about how sites graduate:

> 1. When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.
> 2. If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.
>
> Is your site in between these two categories? You don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site might be, you have a home here in the SE network. Spoiler alert: As of this post, no site which is currently active is at risk of being shut down.

Source: [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614)

So, how do we perform?

1. From [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551/chess), we get 2.2 questions per day
2. I don't have statistics on bullet point 2, but from my own experience, we are nice to one another, we do have enough people helping with flags etc. and we do provide helpful content

From this, we are likely to remain in beta but not be closed down. If we can get 5 times the number of questions per day, then we are likely to graduate. I don't know how we can do that in all honesty.

Comment: Increasing number of _questions per day_ is very difficult.

Comment: I accepted the answer. I agree everything you wrote.

Comment: @KrishnShweta I don't see any possibility.

Comment: @SmallChess How about promoting to programming SEs as well? As we have posts associated to writing softwares for chess.

Comment: @KrishnShweta What do you mean? We're just users, we don't have responsibility to promote the site.

Comment: @SmallChess It meant this: https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/what-would-be-a-good-community-promotion-ad

Comment: The linked Area 51 page now says only 1.5 questions per day. It would be interesting to see how the number of questions per day has evolved over time (say the past few years), to see if the number of questions per day shows any signs of increase at all.

Answer (score -1):

Considering what happened to Productivity.SE, it will be a matter of time before Chess.SE gets closed as well. SE is a business not charity.

Comment: We have six times the number of questions per day and twice the number of visits per day, so I'm not sure if it's comparable.

Comment: @itub the content quality here is much worse, I would nominate this SE as a higher priority for deletion

Comment: Provided there's sufficient base of moderation for a site, it's not in danger of being shut down. If the diamond moderators start stepping down and can't be replaced, that's when we start getting concerned. Low traffic isn't really something we worry about.